# is it possible to Activate Supervised Mode for iOS without DEP or Apple Configurator 2?

Tags: ios

I hop you could help me here :)

so i am trying to activate Supervised Mode for an iPhone 7, ifound until yet just to ways to do that:

1- via Apple Configurator 2 (I cant do that, cause i dont have any mac here to install on it, and there is not Windows Version)

2- via DEP (i cant do that too, cause the iphone 7, which i have here has been bought long ago, so i dont have the dealer-ID to manage it in DEP )

I´ll be very thankful for answering

Thanks,
Jackob

Comment: Those are the only two ways.

Comment: @Paulw11 okay thx for your answer